# Modify values of a CSV based on previous values using awk

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk

I'd like to replace extraneous data values (any value >100,000) of a csv with the previous non-extraneous value.

```
    Input
    1/1/2017 01:00 56242
    1/1/2017 02:00 51214
    1/1/2017 03:00 101442
    1/1/2017 04:00 44242
    1/1/2017 05:00 990919
    1/1/2017 06:00 221512
    1/1/2017 07:00 52100

    Expected Output
    1/1/2017 01:00 56242
    1/1/2017 02:00 51214
    1/1/2017 03:00 51214
    1/1/2017 04:00 44242
    1/1/2017 05:00 44242
    1/1/2017 06:00 44242
    1/1/2017 07:00 52100
```

Can this be done using awk in a bash script?

Something like:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=" "} NF{print $1, $2, ($3 >=100000 "not sure") output.csv
```

Any help would be appreciated - I'm not very familiar with awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk '{if($NF>100000) $NF=p; else p=$NF}1' file
```

Comment: Ah, p is what I was missing! Thank you so much.